# How to edit the specific line in a text file?

Tags: c++, ifstream, ofstream

How should I edit the specific line in a text file? And how should I avoid overwriting issue. ( How do I keep the record I had added before instead of replacing them by the new records?)

I tried to use line.replace but it says " No matching member function for  call to replace ".

```
else if(choice == 4){

//            count++;

    string edit;
    string newdate;
    double newincome;
    double newoutcome;
    double EditTodayBalance = 0;
    string emptySpace = "         ";
//            string sentence;

    cout << " There are " << count << " record(s) in the file " <<     endl;
    cout << " Please enter the date to edit " << endl;
    cin >> edit;



    size_t pos;
    ifstream Record("BankRecord.txt");
    if (Record.is_open()) {
        while (getline(Record, line)) {
            pos = line.find(edit);
            if (pos != string::npos) // string::npos is returned if 
string is not found
                {
                    cout << line << endl;

                    cout << " Enter what you want to replace " << endl;

                    cout << " Please enter the new date you want to put " << endl;
                    cin >> newdate;
                    cout << " Please enter the new income you want to put " << endl;
                    cin >> newincome;
                    cout << " Please enter the new outcome you want to put " << endl;
                    cin >> newoutcome;

                    cout << "            Your new Record is                 " << endl;
                    cout << count << emptySpace << newdate << emptySpace << newincome << emptySpace << newoutcome << endl;


                    //line.replace()
            }
        }
    }
    EditTodayBalance = newincome - newoutcome;
    cout << " Today's balance is " << EditTodayBalance << endl;

    cout << " Please reenter your choice " << endl;
    cin >> choice;
}
```

I expect if the old line is " 1      2/2/2019      32      21 " and I input the new line to be " 1       2/3/2019        22      11 ". Then when I open the file the record will be the new one.

Comment: What you want to the letter isn't achievable in C++. Classic `C` can do the job quite effectively (but it's a nightmare). You can still use `C` code in `C++` assembly. So if you are allowed to do so, you may look at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_file_io.htm and https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fseek.htm 
Again, this is a nightmare and I would not recommend going through the `fseek` stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you will have to re-write the entire file. Read the content of the file line by line, store it in memory (maybe a vector of strings). Now do your editing on the specified line in that vector. When the operation is complete, dump the entire content of vector in another file. You may later replace the original file.

Comment: The vector is optional, and not a good idea if the file is large. This task can be accomplished without it. Read in a line, edit it if needed, write it out to the new file, repeat until done. Then replace the original file with the new file

Comment: Alright, thank you. But I am pretending that the user will open this system a lot of times but how can I rewrite the whole thing to the different files every time? Well, I mean I can't make the program to open a random new text file by itself.

Comment: @HuangMolly Open the original file name (say file_orig) in read mode. Read it and edit the line in memory. Open another file (say file_tmp) in write mode. Write the content/modified content to file_tmp. Close both the files. Delete file_orig. Rename file_tmp to file_orig. You could use 'std::filesystem::copy' for copying file.